# How to get (X,Y) vectors from position and landmark

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry

I currently have an agent in a map, whose position is known as `myPos=(myX,myY)`, but whose orientation `myOri=(oriX,oriY)` is unknown. I also see a landmark at position `lm=(lmX,lmY)` and I have both Cartesian and polar coordinates from my point of view to the landmark, as `relLM=(relX,relY)` and `polLM=(r,theta)`, respectively.

My goal is to find how my orientation vector is related with the X and Y axis, as `XX=(xX, xY)` and `YY=(yX, yY)`. Assume for the following examples that X grows to the right and Y grows upwards, and that an agent with 0 rotation follows the X axis (so an agent looking right has `XX=(1,0)` and `YY=(0,1)`. *This follows from the [intuition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#/media/File:Degree-Radian_Conversion.svg) where 0 angle rotation is on the X axis, PI/2 rotation is on the Y, PI is on -X, 3PI/2 is on -Y and 2PI is X.*

**Example)** If `myOri=(1,1)` (agent is facing top right), then `XX=(1, -1)` (since the X axis is top right to him) and `YY=(1, 1)` (the Y axis is top left). In the picture below, X and Y are shown in red and green. My agent is in blue and the landmark in pink. Hence, our initial data are `myPos=(0,-2)`, `lm=(0,-1)`, `relLM=(~0.7,~0.7)`.

[image: Example image]

By knowing `myPos` and `lmPos`, as well as `relLM`, this should be possible. However, I'm having trouble finding the appropriate vectors. What is the correct algorithm?

```
bool someFunction(Landmark *lm, Vector2f myPos, Vector2f *xx, Vector2f *yy){
    // Vector from agent to landmark
    Vector2f agentToLandmark(lm->position.x - myPos.x,
            lm->position.y - myPos.y);

    // Vector from agent to landmark, regarding agent's orientation
    Vector2f agentFacingLandmark = lm->relPosition.toCartesian();        

    // Set the XX and YY values
    // how?
}
```

*My problem is actually in 3D, but using 2D makes the problem easier to explain.*

Comment: @trincot that's not exactly suitable for math.stackexchange, since the question is rather trivial and will most likely get closed within a pretty short time.

Comment: So, what do you propose? Close because off-topic?

Comment: @trincot yup. Close off-topic. The reason would pretty much stay the same except for the point with transferring the question to math.stackexchange. Or "unclear what you're asking", since the question is stuffed with logic and mathematical mistakes and misconceptions.

Comment: @BlueMoon93 Try to solve the problem on a paper. You'll notice quite a lot of issues with this question: 1. `myOri` is known and equal to `relLM` 2. The point about an axis being "in front of an agent" is from a mathematical point of view simply wrong. There's absolutely no way to define a relation-ship of this kind for two lines.

Comment: Yeah, i had the colors wrong, my bad. But it should be (0.7, 0.7). You can see by the agent referential that you have positive X and Y to reach the landmark. Or am I confusing something? Regarding the `in front of`, it's just a way for me to show you how the agent's maps relative objects. A `relLM=(10,0)` means that the landmark is directly in front of the agent, 10 units away.

Comment: @BlueMoon93 my bad with the `(0.7, 0.7)` issue. I made a mistake. As for the "in front" that issue still remains. You'll have to redefine that for a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Finding myOri

Since `relLM` is `lm` relative to `myOri`, `lm + relLM` must be in `myPos + µ * myOri`. Thus `lm + relLM - myPos = myOri * µ`. Since `µ > 0` must be given in this case, and `myOri` only needs to indicate a direction, it's sufficient to choose an arbitrary `µ > 0`.

### Finding xx and yy

I think your definition of `xx` is simply a vector representing the x-axis from the POV of the agent. And same for `yy` and the y-axis. This can easily be achieved. The angle between `myOri` and the x-axis is equal to the angle between the x-axis and `xx`, thus simply mirror `myOri` at the x-axis and you got `xx`. So `xx = (myOri.x , myOri.y * (-1))`. The angle between `myOri` and the y-axis is equal to the angle between `myOri` and `yy`, so `yy = myOri`.

Note that this is only a guess on what you mean.
Might be that I've misunderstood something. Just notify me if that's the case.

Comment: How is `myOri` known and equal to `relLM`?

Comment: `myOri` is the direction the agent looks, so the vector from `myPos` to `lm`. `relLM` is the vector from the agent to `lm`. So `relLM = lm - myPos` and `myPos + myOri * n = lm`. I should probably have worded that better. There exists `n >= 0` such that `myOri * n = relLM`. I'll edit the answer

Comment: But the agent is not looking towards the landmark. He can be, but he is not necessarily. Have you seen my edit?

Comment: @BlueMoon93 just noticed it. I'll read through that and edit the answer as needed.

Comment: @BlueMoon93 I've edited the answer and hope I understood everything right this time.